# How to check with Pattern if a string comes after string?

Tags: java, regex

How to check with Pattern.compile if a string comes after string? For example, I have String:
`"I love programming a lot!"`
How can I output only the word `programming` if and only if there is a word `love` or `like` before it? What is the regex for that?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest method will be to use

```
.*?(?:love|like).*(programming)
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/xB8bV5/1)**

Using `lookaheads`

```
(?=.*?(love|like).*?(programming))
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/xB8bV5/2)**

*Java Code*

```
String line = "I love programming a lov lot!"; 
String x = "programming";
String pattern = ".*?(?:love|like).*(" + x + ")";
Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);
Matcher m = r.matcher(line);

while (m.find()) {
    String tmp = m.group(1);
    System.out.println(tmp);
}
```

**[Ideone Demo](http://ideone.com/esKyZk)**

Comment: What if I have an arbitrary word after `like` and `love`. Is there any way for that ? @rock321987

Comment: @Maximillan it will work for any word..try it..can you specify the case?

Comment: @Maximillan you need to know that word beforehand..how will you be able to determine which word to match after `love` or `like`?

Comment: @Maximillan If you know the word beforehand(or it is user input), you can concatenate it with regex..

Comment: thats exactly what i want! but how to concatenate? For example, given `I love x` it should print only `x` where `x` can be any word.

Comment: @Maximillan `String regex = ".*(love|like).*(" + x + ")"` ..you can compile this regex and find the results

Comment: @Maximillan see **[this](http://ideone.com/esKyZk)** on ideone

Comment: @Maximillan consider accepting the answer if ti helped

Answer (score 1):

Don't use Pattern, just use `replaceAll()`:

```
String lovedThing = str = str.replaceAll(".*(love|like)\\s+(\\S+).*", "$2");
```

This matches the whole string, replacing it with what's captured in group 2, effectively "extracting" the target, which is matched as "non whitespace chars".

Comment: For example, given I love x it should print only x where x can be any word. @Bohemian

Comment: @max that's what this does

Comment: What is "$2" ? @Bohemian

Comment: @max group 2 from the match. A group is formed using brackets. Groups are numbered starting from 1

Answer (score 0):

This is the essay way to doing this as I think

```
   String s = "I love programming a lot!";

    if (s.contains("like") || s.contains("love")) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String s = "I love programming a lot!";
String condition1 = s.indexOf("love");
String condition2 = s.indexOf("like");
String condition3 = s.indexOf("programming");

    if (condition1 < condition3 || condition2 < condition3) {
        System.out.println("programming"); //or get value if not hardcoded
    }
```